# Best way to test an application on multiple devices without having to make it public?

Tags: laravel, hosting

Okay so first of all, sorry if the title is confusing. I did not know how to word this properly.

The problem I am facing is the fact that I have built a Laravel application, and I need to have my client test it too, naturally. The thing is I would like to avoid buying a domain as it is like a one or two time thing. Are there any ways where I can quickly and easily set up a testing environment that he could access easily despite him and me being on different IP's etc.

If anyone has tips or suggestions that would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngrock ([link to ngrock](https://ngrok.com/)). Just launch your server ( apache maybe or artisan serve ) and then it connects to the ngrok cloud service which accepts traffic on a public address and relays that traffic through to the ngrok process running on your machine and then on to the local address you specified.
The only issue is that the address offered when you are on the free offer doesn't last long, so here you should decide if you really need to get a payed plan or not.

Comment: This sounds amazing, do you happen to know how long it would last? I would need it for not sure, maybe a week or 2 weeks. I need him to test it himself and due to coronavirus I don't really have much options to visit him.

Comment: On top of that, how long does a session last? A youtube clip showed me 8 hours, but when those 8 hours expire can I set up a new session? Is it documented on their site perhaps? That's all I'd need to know honestly

Comment: When the session ends you'll get a new link, send it again to those who wants to test. ( Validate my answer if it really satisfy your need, ty )